# Static methods and inheritance

Tags: c++, design-patterns, glfw

So i'm using an MVC design pattern to manage my scenes in my game.

I have an object named GameLoop with a method called "LoadView" which accepts an object called GameView.
When LoadView is called, it stores the scene in a member variable, and subscribes event handlers to a GLFW window object.

both LoadView and ViewController are abstract classes which will be inherited by individual views and controller objects. The controller contains all the necessary event call backs for the Window, however GLFW only accepts static methods as event handlers.

My question is this; If I load an object which inherits GameController from a method that takes in an abstract GameController class, and I try to access its overloaded on_keypress_event, will it call the on_keypress_event defined by the parent or the abstract object?

I'm basically trying to figure out how to overload a static method.

Should I use a function pointer to grab the handler and subscribe it to the window?

Comment: _"...trying to figure out how to overload a static method..."_ not possible.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to implement this design pattern than if the library only accepts static methods as handlers.

Comment: You'll have to leverage glfwGet/SetWindowUserPointer(), that can be the  pointer you need to turn the static event handler call into a member function call.

Comment: @RichardCritten you can overload a static method easily. What you *can't* do is make it work polymorphically. Polymorphism in C++ requires an object, and static methods aren't connected to an object (they don't have a `this` pointer).

Comment: @HansPassant you should include a warning: you must guard against the pointer being invalidated before the callback is made. Smart pointers won't help you here.

Comment: You say "LoadView stores the scene in a member variable" and  "GLFW only accepts static methods as event handlers".  When you subscribe for the event handler, do you have the option of passing along some context. 
 Something that is remembered and passed back when invoked the event?  If so, that context could be the pointer to your object -- problem solved.  Just write a static handler that knows what the context is, cast it back to the proper type and invoke something virtual

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late update, I've been playing with the code, The best solution to my issue was Hans Passat's answer to use Get/SetWindowUserPointer, thiis object allowed me to pass a reference to my GameLoop class (which contains my Game view, which contains my controller) to the static method handler for on_keypress event. I than grabbed the controller from the getUserPointer method which I than used to call a non static function on_keypress_handler stored within my controller.